# Is a constructor a mutator?

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I need to add 2 constructors and separate from that also mutators are listed. however I thought that most constructors were mutators: as can be seen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711442/java-using-accessor-and-mutator-methods). So I am confused what do I need to do for the mutator methods? I currently have teh bellow for constructors:

```
//Constructors
public Species() {
    speciesName = "Balaenoptera musculus";
    population = 15000;
    growthRATE = -0.12;
    if (endangered(growthRATE) == true) {
        status = "endangered";
    } else {
        status = "not endangered";
    }
}

public Species(String name, int populationSize, double GR) {
    speciesName = name;
    population = populationSize;
    growthRATE = GR;
    if (endangered(GR) == true) {
        status = "endangered";
    } else {
        status = "not endangered";
    }
}

public Species(Species species) {
    speciesName = species.getSpeciesName();
    population = species.getPopulation();
    growthRATE = species.getGrowthRate();
    if (endangered(growthRATE) == true) {
        status = "endangered";
    } else {
        status = "not endangered";
    }
}
```

Based on comments:

Here is what I tried however it lead to teh following error

> The method print(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments 
>    (void)

On this line in main:

```
        Species O5 = O1;
    System.out.print(O5.changeSpeciesName("Gorilla beringei"));
```

The methods look as follows:

```
    public void changeSpeciesName(String newSpeciesName) {
    speciesName = newSpeciesName;
}
```

Comment: No. A constructor is not a mutator.

Comment: So what is an example of a mutator cuz the only ones I found like in teh post I linked were a constructor @ElliottFrisch

Comment: You linked to the other post but did you actually read the accepted answer? [_""Accessor" and "Mutator" are just fancy names fot a getter and a setter"_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15711958/283366)

Comment: `species.getSpeciesName();` is an accessor (or "getter"). A mutator is a method that alters the state of an existing instance (a "setter").

Comment: I suggest you read it again then as the answer includes _getter_ and _setter_ examples

Comment: Ok so I just check taht other answer again and that is what I had tryd however I got an error when calling it on a object I had created in main. How shoudl it be called?

Comment: That entirely depends on what the rest of your code looks like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Using Accessor and Mutator methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711442/java-using-accessor-and-mutator-methods)

Comment: @Phil I edited my answer

Comment: A mutators alters an existing object, a constructor initializes a new object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire point of the constructor is to initialize the instance, and that requires *setting fields* - so you'd think a constructor is a mutator, right? It's a bit of a technicality, but a mutator specifically changes the value of a field *on an existing instance*, whereas a constructor *creates that instance*. A lot of times, the constructor does "mutate" the instance it's creating - but it's a constructor, not a mutator.

Mutators, on the other hand, are specifically methods that *change attributes of the instance*. For example:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

I don't know what your assignment here is exactly, but I have a feeling that you're being told to write mutator methods and then call them in your constructors. For example, instead of

```
speciesName = "Balaenoptera musculus";
speciesName = name;
speciesName = species.getSpeciesName();
```

you should do

```
setName("Balaenoptera musculus");
setName(name);
setName(species.getSpeciesName());
```

Basically, instead of having the constructor change the variables itself, it should call the class's mutator to change the variables.

The general reason that people will tell you to do it this way is out of concern for questions like "what if we change how the name is supposed to be set?" This way, if something changes, we only have to change it in one place: the mutator function `setName()`. Otherwise, we'd have to change each of the constructors, and that's two extra changes - we might forget about one of them, and that would create a bug.

---

However, when using method calls in constructors, make sure that the method you called can't be overridden by derived classes. This could lead to undesired behaviour because code might use partially initialized objects. Resulting errors are hard to find because the code looks ok, but doesn't do what you intended it to do.

You can avoid such problems by using final on your method declaration

```
public final void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

or by avoiding method calls in constructors.

Comment: I added info to my question

Comment: The new error you're getting is because you're trying to print a `void`. Remember, you defined `changeSpeciesName()` as a `void`, meaning it doesn't return anything. Then, you're calling `print(changeSpeciesName(...))`; The print function is looking for something to print - whatever is returned from `chanceSpeciesName()` - but nothing is returned, so there's nothing to print. Thus the error.

Comment: @ModusTollens that's a good point. I don't think I know the subject in quite enough detail to articulate that point well - would you mind suggesting an edit to my answer?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Gladly :). I added some text, but please do look over it, as English is not my first language and I'm not too confident about it!