# i have created a custom class which can get date and time as strings i want to access the object and set data to the class any suggestions

Tags: java

i have created a custom class which can get date and time as strings i want to access the object and set data to the class any suggestions 
here is my code

```
public class DateTime {
private String Date;
private String Time;

public DateTime(String Date,String Time) {
    this.Date=Date;
    this.Time=Time;

}

public void showDateAndTime() {

    System.out.println("entery Date is :");
    System.out.println(Date);
    System.out.println("entery time is :");
    System.out.println(Time);

}
}

public class Vehicle {

        public int ID;
        public String Brand;
            public String type;
        public DateTime entryTimeDate;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        Vehicle v1=new Vehicle();
        v1.entryTimeDate**********
}
```

i want to set date time value to v1 object any suggestions?

Comment: Unclear what is being asked and what has been tried, but
v1 is a Vehicle right? So the compiler won't allow a Vehicle object to be set on a DateTime reference
Side note, try the java.time.LocalDateTime class, much more functionality and testing than rolling your own class

Comment: `v1.entryDateTime = new DateTime("Tomorrow", "now!!!")` or whatever time and date values you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `public` fields in `Vehicle` class, make them `private` and then  [use accessor and mutator methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711442/java-using-accessor-and-mutator-methods) in order to gain access to them. Then `vehicle.getEntryTimeDate()` will be enough to give you the DateTime object of the vehicle. With other words:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private int id;
    public String brand;
    public String type;
    public DateTime entryTimeDate;

    public Vehicle()
    {
        setId(0);
        setBrand("");
        setType("");
        setEntryTimeDate(new DateTime("DATE", "TIME"));
    }

    public Vehicle(int id, String brand, String type, DateTime entryTimeDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.type = type;
        this.entryTimeDate = entryTimeDate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public DateTime getEntryTimeDate() {
        return entryTimeDate;
    }

    public void setEntryTimeDate(DateTime entryTimeDate) {
        this.entryTimeDate = entryTimeDate;
    }

    public static class DateTime{
        private String date;
        private String time;

        public DateTime(String date,String time) {
            this.setDate(date);
            this.setTime(time);

        }

        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(String time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
        v1.getEntryTimeDate().setTime("Time of the vehicle");
        v1.getEntryTimeDate().setDate("Date of the vehicle.");
    }
}
```

---

**Some notes:** Ignore the `static` keyword in `DateTime` class. I did it in order to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also notice the field naming convention i followed (camel-case). It is the most used naming convention by Java programmers.

Comment: it returns Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in lines of ` v1.getEntryTimeDate().setTime("Time of the vehicle");
        v1.getEntryTimeDate().setDate("Date of the vehicle.");`

Comment: @RayanLiyanage I edited my post. It was my mistake indeed. I never initialized the `entryTimeDate` object of the `Vehicle` in the default constructor. So the `getEntryTimeDate` method was returning null. Now the default constructor initializes all the fields, avoiding NPE in all getters.